# What font is used for the Kotaku logo

Tags: fonts, font-identification, logo

Any ideas on what font this is?
[image]

[image]

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/KotakuLogo.jpg

Comment: What do you think of this its not quite the same but its pretty darn close.

http://www.dafont.com/osaka-sans-serif.font

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let' look at this picture -

[image]

The letters "u", "o","r","c","**e**" and "**a**" are close to the font in question (we should point out they all have unusual design), thus we may assume that the designer could use this font as a base, but changed the letters according to his taste...

**DESIGNER BLOCK FONT**

[From here](http://www.k-type.com/?p=296)

PS
I was asked about some "prominent" feature of the font, thus I add here [the font](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/northernblock/platform-one/) from which the idea was probably taken (look at "C" letter endings), also look at capital "**T**" letter which upper part matches exactly to "t" in the logo and lower part was mirrored...

**PlatformOne Black**

[image]

Comment: Very close, but a defining feature of the typeface is the "half-round" end caps. The landing page has a pretty good clue for further research: "Designers Republic" (a design studio/aesthetic school). I expect the "K" is custom. Google also: "Wipeout computer game"

Comment: @horatio I've added the probable source of half-round end caps....

Comment: Yeah it could be a combination of the above.